# Find nearest postive semidefinite matrix keeping diagonal.

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition, diagonalization

Given a symmetric matrix $W$, is there a way to find the nearest positive semidefinite matrix $W_{PS}$ such that it is nearest to $W$ by some criterion (e.g. Frobenius norm) but it is such that $\text{diag}(W) = \text{diag}(W_{PS})$?

Comment: Not sure about an exact method, but maybe try looking up semi-definite programming.